# pg_copy_from will not let my index column increment itself, and will not take blank value either

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, insert

I have an array I would like to use to populate a pgsql table using `pg_copy_from`. But I get the following error when I don't give it information for my serial `index` column.

```
ERROR: there is data for a column index
```

How can I force `pg_copy_from` to ignore my index column and just let it increment independently. Since it takes comma-separated values I tried doing sometime like this to pass it a blank string in index's position:

```
array_walk($logs, function(&$record) { 
    "'', " . $record; 
});
```

But it did not work. I also tried making a table where `index` was the second column, and I didn't pass a second value, but I received the same error. Is there an option for this?

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER**.  I'm not a PHP developer, but it sounds like you probably need to just insert the word DEFAULT into your array for your "index" column (and I'm assuming this in your primary key and it's got a sequencer).  For example:

```
create temp table foobar(id serial, foo text);
insert into foobar values (DEFAULT, 'hello');
insert into foobar values (DEFAULT, 'world');
select * from foobar;
+----+-------+
| id |  foo  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | hello |
|  2 | world |
+----+-------+
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

pg_copy_from doesn't allow you to exclude some columns. A combination of pg_query and pg_put_line does allow this because of your own COPY statement:

```
<?php 
  $conn = pg_pconnect("dbname=foo");
  pg_query($conn, "create table bar (a serial, b char(16), d float8)"); // just an example
  pg_query($conn, "copy bar(b, c) from stdin"); // only columns b and c !
  pg_put_line($conn, "hello world\t4.5\n");
  pg_put_line($conn, "goodbye world\t7.11\n");
  pg_put_line($conn, "\\.\n");
  pg_end_copy($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this. I'm curious, why does this: `array_walk($logs, function (&$item, $key) {  $item = time() . $key . ", " . $item;});` concatenation produce the error `PHP Warning:  pg_copy_from(): Copy command failed: ERROR:  missing data for column "entry"